# How to redirect everything ending with .htm?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In short, I want all pages ending with .htm to redirect to one single page.

I have a newsarchive with a lot of news articles. They all end with .htm so I want all urls ending with .htm to redirect to one single page

How do I do this?

Comment: This is explained in detail in the excellent documentation. Assuming that you use standard components like the apache http server and its rewriting module.  So why ask here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 \.html$ /single-page
```

EDIT: Fixed typo in `RedirectMatch`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I allready found that this would also work: RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /single-page [R=301,L] What is the difference?

Comment: That is provided by `mod_rewrite` module and my rule is powered by `mod_alias`. That is the only difference, effect is same.